# Pandas - match column from two df and return value from another columnl

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv of transactions from my bank, and another csv that I have created where I have categorized the most frequently occurring transactions. I want to classify the bank csv with a category by matching the Descriptions between both dataframes. Not all will be classified/have a match.

df1 ~2.5k rows:

```
Description, Amount    
Corner Store, 30
Cinema, 10
Trampoline Store, 20
```

df2 ~100 rows:

```
Description, Category
Corner Store, Groceries
Cinema, Recreation
The Pub, Alcohol
```

Want the result:

```
Description, Amount, Category
Corner Store, 30, Groceries
Cinema, 10, Recreation
Trampoline Store, 20,
```

I have tried this but just get a Category column with 'nan' in my df:

```
df1['Category'] = df1['Description'].map(df2.set_index('Description')['Category'])
```

Comment: Read this article: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas' [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), but you need to set the `'Descritpion'` as the index:

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Description':['Corner Store','Cinema','Trampoline Store'],
         'Amount':[30,10,20]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Description':['Corner Store','Cinema', 'The Pub'],
         'Category':['Groceries','Recreation','Alcohol']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1.set_index('Description',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Description',inplace=True)

df3 = df1.join(df2)
print(df3)
```

outputs:

```py
                  Amount    Category
Description                         
Corner Store          30   Groceries
Cinema                10  Recreation
Trampoline Store      20         NaN
```